# Why does Google's inspector mobile tool render content different than my iphone

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a pretty simple website, which renders a background image, a header, a footer, and some body text.

When I view the site from Google Dev Tools mobile inspector. The text sits above the footer as expected.  When I view the site from an actual iphone the text is shown at the very bottom of the page (behind the footer).

App.js

```
return (
      <div className={style.app}>
        <Header setNav={setNav} nav={nav} />
        <Routes>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/"
            element={
              <Mobile
                setNav={setNav}
                nav={nav}
                menuList={menuList}
                setFilter={setFilter}
              />
            }
          />
          <Route
            exact
            path="/directions"
            element={
              <Directions
                setNav={setNav}
                nav={nav}
                filter={filter}
                setFilter={setFilter}
                menuList={menuList}
              />
            }
          />
        </Routes>

        <MobileNavOneButton setNav={setNav} setFilter={setFilter} />
      </div>
    );
```

the css for style.app is:

```
.app {
  background-image: url("../CompanyImages/Port507BackgroundImage.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -999;
}
```

Mobile.js

```
import React from "react";
import style from "./Mobile.module.css";

const Mobile = () => {
  return (
    <div className={style.app}>
      <div className={style.mainContent}>
        <div className={style.address}>128 W 2nd St, Winona, MN 55987</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Mobile;
```

css for mobile.js

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  /* height: 100% */
}

.app {
  height: calc(100vh - 8rem);
  width: 100vw;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 5rem;
}

.mainContent {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-self: flex-end;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
```

Footer.js

```
import React from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import style from "./MobileNavOneButton.module.css";
import HomeIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Home";
import ExploreIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Explore";

const MobileNavOneButton = ({ setNav }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <div className={style.NavBar}>
      <div
        className={style.NavButton}
        onClick={() => {
          navigate("../directions", { replace: true });
          setNav(false);
        }}
      >
        <ExploreIcon style={{ fontSize: "1.25rem", color: "#000000" }} />
        <div className={style.buttonText}>Directions</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MobileNavOneButton;
```

css for the footer

```
.buttonText {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  font-family: Montserrat-Light;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.NavBar {
  width: 100%;
  float: none;
  display: flex;
  height: 3rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.8);
}

.NavButton {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* border: 1px solid black; */
  /* background-color: rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.8); */
  border-radius: 0;
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-family: Montserrat-Light;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #222222;
}

.NavButton:focus {
  outline: none !important;
  outline-offset: none !important;
}
```

The website can be seen here. Note: you will be redirected if viewing from a browser (need to be in Dev Tools mobile)

[Website](https://www.port507.com)

Comment: That's because all browsers on iOS actually uses the same webkit rendered under the hood due to restrictions. The mobile emulator on your Chrome is using chromium.

Comment: @Terry, got it. But based on the css for `mobile.js` shouldn't the `app` class only be as large as the empty space `calc(100vh - 8rem)`?

I'm not seeing why on any device the text would float to the bottom.